# Floating point error in while loop in C++

Tags: c++, c, compilation

```
int main()
 {
      float x = k ; // k is some fixed positive value 
      while(x>0)
           x-- ;
      return 0 ;
 }
```

**Can above program go in infinite loop ?**

Comment: I think there are some values where it may happen. It was an interview problem. I am not sure though.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg With all the undefined behavior in C++, these types of questions should be asked.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg This is a silly answer. For most values it does terminate. Finding a non-terminating number is not obvious to all.

Comment: Another option to get it into an infinite loop: Start with k = +infinity

Comment: @dornhege this isn't a positive number

Comment: @stefan: In IEEE 754, infinity is both positive and a number.

Comment: @EricPostpischil really? that's terrible. Did no mathematician ever took part at the discussion on how to define that?!

Comment: @stefan: Many mathematicians contributed to IEEE 754. Infinity is a valid number in some arithmetic systems. What is your problem with it?

Comment: @EricPostpischil It's fairly unusual to treat infinity as a number. In the field of real numbers, there is no infinity, it is just a concept to express limits of sequences. As floats usually imitate real numbers, infinity shouldn't be defined as a number.

Comment: @stefan: Given that floating-point arithmetic **imitates** real numbers, there are necessarily deviations between floating-point arithmetic and real arithmetic. Including infinity in the values is a way of dealing with those limitations that makes floating-point arithmetic more useful than if it did not provide a value to represent the results of operations that exceeded the finite range. Again: What is your specific computing problem caused by treating infinity as a number? Is your objection just philosophical or does it cause an actual problem?

Comment: @EricPostpischil It does cause problems: The difference of infinity and a number is not defined, but is infinity itself (following the usual rules of operations on inf). Saying "infinity is a number" says, "infinity should follow the same rules as other numbers" which it clearly doesn't. infinity is not a "normal" number, not even in IEEE754, so why call it a number in the first place. It's wrong. This isn't philosophical.

Comment: @stefan: I do not understand your statement that the difference between infinity and another number is not defined but is infinity. The difference is defined to be infinity, so it is not undefined. Please show some software that this causes problems for.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Oh I made a mistake in my last comment, you're right. I was distracted, I'm sorry. Anyway: The problem isn't software, it is that the concept of infinity doesn't match the concept of numbers. So it's wrong to put the same label on them (i.e. declaring inf as a number). E.g. for a number `x`, `x - x` should be zero. `inf - inf` isn't zero, hence it is not a number: http://ideone.com/YgCuDB

Comment: Floats do exactly the right thing here, `x-x` with x as `inf` gives you not a number (`nan`). This might be more of a philosophical problem. After all it is just definitions of a) Are there "special" float values allowed like `inf`, `nan` and b) if yes, how do we treat them. What I've seen from floats is that they usually do what I'd like them to do even involving `inf` and `nan`. Or in other words: If your calculations might involve or result in non-numbers, floats do the best they can to produce the most reasonable result. However, if you want correct behavior, you must think of these cases.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes it's possible. Take the maximum float as an example.

As this code illustrates, for the biggest float `m`, `m` equals `m - 1`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {
    auto m = std::numeric_limits<float>::max();
    auto l = m;
    l--;
    std::cerr << (m == l) << "\n";
}
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/Wr9zdN

Therefore, with this start value, the loop will be infinite.

Why is that?

`float` has (as every other built-in type) a limited precision. To make `x - 1` representable by a number other than `x`, the difference between the biggest number smaller than `x` must be less than 2.

Now let's calculate the difference between `m`, the maximum float and `x`, the biggest float, which is strictly less than `m`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>

int main() {
    auto m = std::numeric_limits<float>::max();
    std::cout << "float max: " << m << "\n";
    auto x = std::nextafter(m, 0.0f);
    std::cout << "biggest value less than max: " << x << "\n";
    auto d = m - x;
    std::cout << "the difference: " << d << "\n";
}
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/VyNgtE

Turns out, there is a huge gap of `2.02824e+31` between those two numbers. Far bigger than 1. 1 is simply too tiny to make a difference.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it can. If `k` is `FLT_MAX` for example. There's not enough precision to handle such small distance between such big numbers.

```
#include <float.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float a = FLT_MAX;
    float b = a - 1;
    printf("%.10f\n", a - b);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0.0000000000
```

Comment: You are correct :), Adding a link of @[Codepade: of infinite-loop](http://codepad.org/xgn46vst)

Comment: Relying on the output of the difference isn't a good idea, there might be an error in that. Just check for equality. This asserts bitwise equality.

Comment: I though it was a better way to demonstrate that it wasn't 1 as expected, but 0.

Comment: Can it happen if x is of int data type ?

Comment: @stefan: In binary IEEE 754, subtraction of two numbers close in value (each is at least half the other) is exact; there is no rounding error. Even if they are not close, the result is zero if and only if the numbers are equal.

Comment: @EricPostpischil There is no actual guarantee in C++ that a float follows `IEEE 754`.

Comment: @stefan: No modern floating-point system will return non-zero for subtraction of unequal numbers. That was a deficiency of old systems with poor handling of underflow, so it would happen only with tiny numbers. That cannot happen in this situation, since one is not tiny. Therefore, this code will work (correctly showing zero for no difference) for any floating-point system in use, old or new.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Well anyway: You can rely on "number is zero => will print as zero", but you can't on the reverse. That's why printing a difference is not optimal.

Answer (score 4):

I think it can, actually. If `k` is big enough rounding will devour your decrement.